# How to change timestamp format of type=date in Vuetify text field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I am attempting to bind a start and end date to Vue.js component using a Vuetify text field with type="date". The date format by default returns as MM-DD-YYYY. However I need the dates to return in the format YYYY-MM-DD. How can I can I configure the date type for these fields to return as YYYY-MM-DD. Here is my  the current setup of my field:

```
<v-text-field v-model="start" type="date" label="start"></v-text-field>
<v-text-field v-model="end" type="date" label="end"></v-text-field>
```

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Vuetify calendar date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57717902/how-to-change-vuetify-calendar-date-format)

Comment: not the same question at all

Answer (score 0):

You can use vuetify date picker

```
<v-menu
    v-model="startDtMenu"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    :nudge-right="40"
    transition="scale-transition"
    offset-y
    min-width="290px"
    >
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-text-field
        :value="dayjs(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD')"
        label="Work Date*"
        readonly
        dense
        v-on="on"
        ></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker v-model="start" @input="startDtMenu= false"></v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

and in the data property you can define

```
data(){
  return{
   startDtMenu: false,
   start: '',
  }
}
```