# How to change Vuetify calendar date format

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am attempting to enable inputted events on the following Vuetify calendar:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/calendars/complex/events.vue.

I have set up my calendar to accept inputted data submitted in a form, including name, details, start, end, color. When I submit the form, an error occurs saying that

> the start and end properties are required on all events to be a valid timestamp in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

I am using type="date" in the start and end input fields, which render the dates in the MM-DD-YYYY. I tried using the Vuetify date picker instead in order to get the fields to render in YYYY-MM-DD format, but to no avail. How can I reconfigure this calendar to instead accept MM-DD-YYYY format for dates?

CALENDAR MODIFIED:

moment added to function

```
      async addEvent () {
        this.start = await new Date(this.start).toISOString().substring(0,10)
        this.end =  await new Date(this.end).toISOString().substring(0,10)
        this.events.push({name: this.name})
        this.events.push({details: this.details})
        this.events.push({start: this.start})
        this.events.push({end: this.end})
        this.events.push({color: this.color})
      },
```

Full Code

```
<template>
  <v-row class="fill-height">
    <v-col>
      <v-sheet height="64">
        <v-toolbar flat color="white">
          <v-btn outlined class="mr-4" @click="setToday">
            Today
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn fab text small @click="prev">
            <v-icon small>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn fab text small @click="next">
            <v-icon small>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn
            color="primary"
            dark
            @click.stop="dialog = true"
          >
            New Event
          </v-btn>
          <v-toolbar-title>{{ title }}</v-toolbar-title>
          <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
        </v-toolbar>
      </v-sheet>

      <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500">
        <v-card>
          <v-container>
            <v-form @submit.prevent="addEvent">
              <v-text-field v-model="name" type="text" label="name"></v-text-field>
              <v-text-field v-model="details" type="text" label="detail"></v-text-field>
              <v-text-field v-model="start" type="date" label="start"></v-text-field>
              <v-text-field v-model="end" type="date" label="end"></v-text-field>
              <v-text-field v-model="color" label="color"></v-text-field>
              <v-btn type="submit" color="success" class="mr-4" @click.stop="dialog = false">
                submit
              </v-btn>
            </v-form>
          </v-container>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>

      <v-sheet height="600">
        <v-calendar
          ref="calendar"
          v-model="focus"
          color="primary"
          :events="events"
          :event-color="getEventColor"
          :event-margin-bottom="3"
          :now="today"
          :type="type"
          @click:event="showEvent"
          @click:more="viewDay"
          @click:date="viewDay"
          @change="updateRange"
        ></v-calendar>
        <v-menu
          v-model="selectedOpen"
          :close-on-content-click="false"
          :activator="selectedElement"
          full-width
          offset-x
        >
          <v-card
            color="grey lighten-4"
            min-width="350px"
            flat
          >
            <v-toolbar
              :color="selectedEvent.color"
              dark
            >
              <v-btn icon>
                <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
              <v-toolbar-title v-html="selectedEvent.name"></v-toolbar-title>
              <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
              <v-btn icon>
                <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn icon>
                <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </v-toolbar>
            <v-card-text>
              <span v-html="selectedEvent.details"></span>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn
                text
                color="secondary"
                @click="selectedOpen = false"
              >
                Cancel
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-menu>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
  //import moment from 'moment'
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      today: '2019-01-08',
      focus: '2019-01-08',
      type: 'month',
      typeToLabel: {
        month: 'Month',
        week: 'Week',
        day: 'Day',
        '4day': '4 Days',
      },
      name: null,
      details: null,
      start: null,
      end: null,
      color: null,
      selectedEvent: {},
      selectedElement: null,
      selectedOpen: false,
      events: [
        {
          name: 'Vacation',
          details: 'Going to the beach!',
          start: '2018-12-29',
          end: '2019-01-01',
          color: 'blue',
        }
      ],
      dialog: false,
    }),
    computed: {
      title () {
        const { start, end } = this
        if (!start || !end) {
          return ''
        }
        const startMonth = this.monthFormatter(start)
        const endMonth = this.monthFormatter(end)
        const suffixMonth = startMonth === endMonth ? '' : endMonth
        const startYear = start.year
        const endYear = end.year
        const suffixYear = startYear === endYear ? '' : endYear
        const startDay = start.day + this.nth(start.day)
        const endDay = end.day + this.nth(end.day)
        switch (this.type) {
          case 'month':
            return `${startMonth} ${startYear}`
          case 'week':
          case '4day':
            return `${startMonth} ${startDay} ${startYear} - ${suffixMonth} ${endDay} ${suffixYear}`
          case 'day':
            return `${startMonth} ${startDay} ${startYear}`
        }
        return ''
      },
      monthFormatter () {
        return this.$refs.calendar.getFormatter({
          timeZone: 'UTC', month: 'long',
        })
      },
    },
    methods: {
      viewDay ({ date }) {
        this.focus = date
        this.type = 'day'
      },
      getEventColor (event) {
        return event.color
      },
      setToday () {
        this.focus = this.today
      },
      prev () {
        this.$refs.calendar.prev()
      },
      next () {
        this.$refs.calendar.next()
      },
      async addEvent () {
        this.start = await new Date(this.start).toISOString().substring(0,10)
        this.end =  await new Date(this.end).toISOString().substring(0,10)
        console.log(this.start)
        this.events.push({name: this.name})
        this.events.push({details: this.details})
        this.events.push({start: this.start})
        this.events.push({end: this.end})
        this.events.push({color: this.color})
      },
      showEvent ({ nativeEvent, event }) {
        const open = () => {
          this.selectedEvent = event
          this.selectedElement = nativeEvent.target
          setTimeout(() => this.selectedOpen = true, 10)
        }
        if (this.selectedOpen) {
          this.selectedOpen = false
          setTimeout(open, 10)
        } else {
          open()
        }
        nativeEvent.stopPropagation()
      },
      updateRange ({ start, end }) {
        // You could load events from an outside source (like database) now that we have the start and end dates on the calendar
        this.start = start
        this.end = end
      },
      nth (d) {
        return d > 3 && d < 21
          ? 'th'
          : ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th'][d % 10]
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: where's the the calendar in your code? please add more code

Comment: I added the code for the calendar above. Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to `moment.js` which will be used only for 2 lines of code, so you could do it simply like :

```
   addEvent () {
        this.start = new Date(this.start).toISOString().substring(0,10);
        this.end =  new Date(this.end).toISOString().substring(0,10);
        ...
            this.events.push({name: this.name,
                              details: this.details,
                              start: this.start,
                              end: this.end,
                             color: this.color})
```

See the Pen 
  [Vuetify Example Pen](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/JjPyRgq/) by boussadjra ([@boussadjra](https://codepen.io/boussadjra))
  on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: I updated the code above. Moment removed. ```console.log(this.start)``` shows that the date is formatted as YYYY-MM-DD, but then I still get the format error message: ```the start and end properties are required on all events to be a valid timestamp in the format YYYY-MM-DD```.

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 i think the problem is in the push method you should push one object with the given fields as i mentioned in my edited answer

Comment: OK that worked! Thank you! This solution to also work without ```this.start = new Date(this.start).toISOString().substring(0,10);``` and ```this.end =  new Date(this.end).toISOString().substring(0,10);```. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 4):

As the developer of the Vuetify calendar, here's my two cents. The reason why events take a string is to distinguish between an all-day event and an event that is timed. An all-day event is in the format of YYYY-MM-DD and a timed event has the date format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss (where seconds is optional, and numbers don't need to be zero padded.)

Having said that, when this PR is merged in and released you will be able to pass dates or UTC timestamps:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/11198

You can then define a function or property on the event that marks it as a timed event.

Answer (score 2):

I would advice to format your date to `MM-DD-YYYY` instead of modifying vuetify, then convert it to whatever format you need when you submit the form.

[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/) is an awesome library for this type of conversions and has an easy API.

In your case, you could simply do `this.end = moment(this.end).format('MM-DD-YYYY');`

Comment: I updated the code above with moment. Still doesn't work though. Moment is installed, but should I be adding ```this.start = moment(this.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD')``` to the addEvent function?

Comment: Do you get a start date from an external resource today? If so, right after you get the data, instead of saying `this.start = response.data.start` say `this.start = moment(response.data.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 Is it a nodejs application?